# Apalike-letters and non-English (Polish) characters (alphabibitem)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, characters, apa-style

I'm using apalike-letters bibliography style which inserts heading for each first letter of authors' names. It works well for English letters but when a name starts with Polish letter it starts to get crazy. Consider following example:

[image: Bibliography with Polish letters]

Note that the order of the items is correct (*Ł* should be after *L* and *Ś* should be after *S*) but first letters of *Łuszczewski* and *Śpiewak* are replaced with their second letters.

I think that it is caused by `purify` function which strips non-alphanumeric characters from string (and *Ł* and *Ś* are not treated as alphanumeric) but I don't know how to change this. All I managed to do is to change *Ł* to `\L` but then *Łuszczewski* was inserted in *L* section which is not correct.

Any ideas how to change this?

You can find the whole project (with the style file in it) at http://piec.info/apalike-letters_test2.zip [76 KB].

Comment: I don't think that you can use this style with initial other than plain latin characters. I tried to use `bibtex8`, but it fails.

Comment: @egreg Actually I'm using `bibtex8.exe -c cp1250pl.csf file` in my real project.

Comment: I get `can't start a style-file command---line 26 of file apalike-letters.bst` and an empty `.bbl` file.

Comment: Although you don't want to hear this (I know you mentioned problems with it in your previous question), but I really think you should try to get this working with `biblatex` and `biber` which have much better methods for sorting non-English alphabets.